# Tracking time user has spent on a page in scala js

Tags: javascript, dom, scala.js

Suppose I want to track how much time the user has spent on the page. If a user has moved to another tab, minimized the browser etc then that time should be also be ignored. I've tried using onfocusout but it is not working.
I've just tried to implement total time without ignoring any time spent on another tab. But I am not getting any success.

```
document.onload={(e:dom.Event)=>
  load_time=System.currentTimeMillis()
}
document.onfocusout={
  (e:dom.Event)=>
    end_time=System.currentTimeMillis()
    println("Time spent on the page is : "+(end_time-load_time) )
}
```

Further, can you suggest how can I ignore the time spent on another tab or when the browser is minimized. I am using scala js. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried it myself yet, but I believe the best way to do that is with [the Page Visibility API](https://www.w3.org/TR/page-visibility/) -- that appears to be implemented in all major browsers by now, and I think it's designed to do essentially what you're looking for...